# Allow null values in a field in flask-restx / flask-restplus

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I am using flask-restx for building an API.

My api model is like the following:

```
myModel = api.model(
    'myModel', 
    {
        'id' : fields.Integer(min=1, required=True),
        'code' : fields.String(enum=["A", "B", "C"], required=False),
    }
)
```

By doing so, code cannot be null.

But sometimes, the code field is null. If it is not, it must be one of the `A`, `B` or `C` values.

I cannot add `None` to the enum list because it is not a string.

How to make it possible to be null ?

Answer (score 6):

add in your script

```
class NullableString(fields.String):
    __schema_type__ = ['string', 'null']
    __schema_example__ = 'nullable string'
```

Then

```
myModel = api.model(
    'myModel', 
    {
        'id' : fields.Integer(min=1, required=True),
        'code' : NullableString(enum=["A", "B", "C"], required=False),
    }
)
```

This should allow your field to be null

Comment: Update to `flask-resplus==0.13.0` and then  use @Stefan Answer. It will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

echo Stefan's answer, and one more thing is that if you want other types such as a nullable List, you can do:

```
class NullableList(fields.List):
    def schema(self):
        schema = super(NullableList, self).schema()
        schema.update(type=['array', 'null'])
    return schema
```

this is because some fields that has overriden the schema() function, and only define __schema_type__ is no longer useful